# Can't Restart Capture Session After Dismissing

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I have a button that starts an `AVCaptureSession` to scan barcodes. It all works fine unless you cancel the `session` or you scan a barcode and decide to scan another one instead. In order to bring it up again, the view controller has to be dismissed and then presented again.

The error when trying to start the session again is in `setUpCaptureSession()`

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
var captureLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
```

Here are the relevent methods.

```
@IBAction func scanBarcode(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.setupCaptureSession()
    }

func cancel() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("backPressed", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

func cancelBarcodeScan() {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()
        self.captureLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "done")
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = "cancel"
    }

private func setupPreviewLayer(completion:() -> ()) {
        self.captureLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

        if let capLayer = self.captureLayer {
            capLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            capLayer.frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(capLayer)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = "cancelBarcodeScan"
            completion()
        } else {
            self.showError("An error occured beginning video capture.")
        }
    }

    private func addMetaDataCaptureOutToSession() {
        let metaData = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        self.captureSession.addOutput(metaData)
        // metaData.metadataObjectTypes = metaData.availableMetadataObjectTypes
        metaData.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode]
        metaData.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    }

    private func setupCaptureSession() {
        self.captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        let deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput)) {
            // Show live feed
            captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
            self.setupPreviewLayer({
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
                self.addMetaDataCaptureOutToSession()
            })
        } else {
            self.showError("Error while setting up input captureSession.")
        }
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        for metaData in metadataObjects {
            let decodedData: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject = metaData as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            upcTextField.text = decodedData.stringValue
            itemNameTextField.text = decodedData.type
            getProductData(decodedData.stringValue)
            self.captureSession.stopRunning()
            self.captureLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "done")
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = "cancel"
        }
    }

    private func showError(error:String)
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let dismiss:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler:{(alert:UIAlertAction!) in
            alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })
        alertController.addAction(dismiss)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029585/raginggoat Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue this is how I resolved it, I just added a captureSession.stopRunning()
captueSession.StartRunning()

```
 if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
//                messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
                let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

                if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
                    // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
                    let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
                    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

                    guard let url = URL(string: metadataObj.stringValue!) else {
                            return
                            }
                        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
                            captureSession.stopRunning()
                            captureSession.startRunning()
```